# Provision profile not add to my iPod (4.2.1)?

Tags: xcode, ipod-touch, provisioning-profile

hi I'm using iPod version 4.2.1 and my xcode version is 3.2.6 i tried to add the provision profile to my iPod but it show "xcode cannot find the software image to install the version". Please give me the solution or alternative method to add the provision profile to my iPod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake this is the problem in iPod date instead of 2011 it set as 2012 so all profile shows as expired

Thanks for all support